# Regarding Mapping Language and How we can convert data into triples?

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, ontology, triples

Firstly, I have created an Ontology using Protege without any individuals. Basically, it's a x.owl file where it is storing the info about relations/properties(object), subject, domain, range and class details in both of the RDF/XML format or in the Turtle format.

eg: Turtle format

```
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

:eventPlayed rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
         rdfs:domain :Situation ;
         rdfs:range :Event .

:hasGender rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
       rdfs:domain :Athlete ;
       rdfs:range :Gender .
```

similar file in the RDF/XML format.

Also, I have a huge dataset in the CSV format.

What I want is to make a mapping file so that I can use both owl+csv files to convert it into triples. So, how can I create a mapping file as the data is fairly large? And How can we make triples with ontology and csv files?

eg:

```
bob Typeof Athlete
bob hasGender Male
bob eventPlayed Football
```

Comment: then you should read about r2rml or even more simple look for an CSV To RDF tool and just convert your data - that's pretty simple

Comment: I recommend [Tarql](http://tarql.github.io) for converting CSV to RDF. (I'm a contributor to the project.)

Comment: Thanks ... But I am little confused now ... I have already created the relationships using the protege and it is in owl format with ranges, domain , object property etc. My csv contains data only. Now if I use any of the software I have to again create the relationships for mapping. Then what is the purpose of that owl file?

Comment: The purpose of the OWL file to have also triples about the schema, like class hierarchy, domain, range of properties, characteristics of properties (transitive, functional, etc) - just everything that you wouldn't define via a mapping of CSV data to RDF data.

Comment: How large your CSV is? Try Cellfie.